# Remove back bar button title Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I want to remove back bar button title. But my code not working.

```
class SearchFoodsTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate {

    var searchController: UISearchController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController:  nil)

        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.delegate = self
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self

        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true

        navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar
        //it is not working
        navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = nil//UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)

        definesPresentationContext = true
    }
```

Result look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CcHJ.png).
How to correctly remove the title? I know this trick in master controller:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    navigationItem.title = "Категории"
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(true)

    navigationItem.title = ""
}
```

It working, but title "Категории" shows up very slowly when I go back in master controller and this solution is not suitable for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the `backBarButtonItem` for the **previous** view controller:

```
class FirstVC: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.title = "FirstVC"
        navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: nil, style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    }
}

class SecondVC: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.title = "SecondVC"
    }
}
```